# How do I extract the data in a specific key in a database by selecting a record from a list

Tags: android, database, sqlite, textview

I write because I am unfortunately stuck in my project and I hope you can help me. 
How do I extract the data in a specific key in a database by selecting a record from a list? For example in a contact database. In this database of contacts, the following keys are used: name, phone, email and address; my problem is, I only need to extract the data from the email key for example and put it in a TextView to be located in another Activity.

What should I do?

In a tutorial I found called ContactManager is something similar done when you select a record from a list, and when he appeared the contact options menu and select delete contact, the contact is removed from the list and of course removed from the database also . But to do it in this way, all the keys contained in the contact record is selected, and as I said I do not need to delete the record, I only need to extract the data from a specific key and put it in a TextView to be located in another activity.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

**This is the code that references the record in the list:**

```
    contactListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> MemberContact, View view, int positioncontact, long identidad) {
            longClickedItemIndex = positioncontact;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**This is the code that determines the position of the record in the list:**

```
private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    public ContactListAdapter() {
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, Contacts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int positioncontact, View view, ViewGroup MemberContact) {
        if (view == null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, MemberContact, false);

        Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(positioncontact);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        name.setText(currentContact.getName());
        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
        TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
        address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**This is the code that refers to the registry to remove it from the database:**

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT:
            // TODO: Implement editing a contact
            break;
        case DELETE:
            dbHandler.deleteContact(Contacts.get(longClickedItemIndex));
            Contacts.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
            contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: can you be more descriptive , I dont understand what exactly you want to do? do you want delete only email entry from database for a particular key? or you need to transfer the details to another activity?
For latter : I hope you know about - Bundle and putString() methods and then transfering bundle with intent

Comment: Hello. Sorry for not answer immediately.
Yes, what I want is to pass the record details to another activity. For example. In a ListView just contact keys will be listed and select it from the ListView will display the following keys: contact, phone, email and address in another activity.

Comment: That is what I want is a query, but instead of doing the query by typing the contact's name in an EditText what I want is that the query is done simply by selecting the contact name from the ListView and others keys in that record are put into a TextView to phone, a TextView to email and TextView to address.

Comment: Hello. I sincerely ask you to forgive me for not having answered your question immediately. Please help me with my question.

Comment: That is what I want is a query, but instead of doing the query by typing the contact's name in an EditText what I want is that the query is done simply by selecting the contact name from the ListView and others keys in that record are put into a TextView to phone, a TextView to email and TextView to address.